# Too many connections are getting created

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

I have gone through the HikariCP connection pool, I could say this is awesome as I have seen good performance. But here my concern is I think it is taking too many connections.

**Scenario:**
I have list object which contains 10004 records and when I ran insert query it is taking 13 seconds to complete the operation.

**DB Properties:**

```
final HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@g9u1769.houston.hpecorp.net:1525:ODSDBD");
dataSource.setUsername("Solid_batch1");
dataSource.setPassword("solid_batch123");
dataSource.setMaxLifetime(30000);
```

**log:**

```
2016-08-27 11:26:01.779 [] [] [] [Hikari connection adder (pool HikariPool-0)] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-0 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@221e8d6a
2016-08-27 11:26:04.204 [] [] [] [Hikari connection adder (pool HikariPool-0)] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-0 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@3c4ecbf
2016-08-27 11:26:06.620 [] [] [] [Hikari connection adder (pool HikariPool-0)] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-0 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@7592f187
2016-08-27 11:26:09.038 [] [] [] [Hikari connection adder (pool HikariPool-0)] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-0 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@22f125f
2016-08-27 11:26:11.455 [] [] [] [Hikari connection adder (pool HikariPool-0)] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-0 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@605f1c17
2016-08-27 11:26:13.869 [] [] [] [Hikari connection adder (pool HikariPool-0)] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-0 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@42d5b6f
2016-08-27 11:26:13.975 [] [] [] [main] WARN  c.h.i.i.d.manager.dao.DaoService - detail query : 13
```

Can anyone help me in reducing the connection creation.

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce maximum pool size so connection will be restrict to that and then it not make more connection instead it will use once defined connection is free to use by setting :

```
 dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
```